# Amazon simple notification service for web apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I want to receive notifications using amazon simple notification service in my android,iOs and web apps. I found, how to enable this in android and ios, but could someone please help me that is it possible to do the same in my web app(node js)? If yes, then how??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following gist -> https://gist.github.com/tmarshall/6149ed2475f964cda3f5

It shows you how to interface with SNS from a Node.js app.

And here is the documentation to the SDK itself - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to support receiving or subscribing to the SNS notifications in the web app. iOS and Android come with services to process push notifications, you would have to build this for your app.

You can send SNS to an http endpoint but it may be easier for you to send notifications to SQS for your node app to consume.

I can't find an npm package for subscribing to SNS but there is a good blog post here https://deepstream.io/blog/publishing-aws-sns-messages-to-browsers-tutorial/